# IOException: "A required privilege is not held by the client." best way to overcome?

Tags: c#, security

I'm writing Winform app using C#. While attempting to create a text file, I got the error "A required privilege is not held by the client." which I googled, has something to do with user's privileges. Simply put, I am not allowed to create a file in my chosen path, which is C:/

Tried this solution: http://www.technitips.com/2010/06/a-required-privilege-is-not-held-by-the-client-windows-7/, only worked once. What's the best way to overcome this kind of error? Should I change my entire Window's security setting? Or change the path to somewhere that  does not need Admin's permission?

Comment: You can also try opening Visual Studio in "Run as administrator" mode to avoid this error in many cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe find a better folderpath  with a call to [GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
```

From the msdndoc for the [SpecialFolder enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

> The directory that serves as a common repository for documents. This
>   member is equivalent to MyDocuments.

If you only need to create a temporary file you can call:

```
Path.GetTempFilename();
```

which `Creates a uniquely named, zero-byte temporary file on disk and returns the full path of that file`, see the [msdn doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx)